# Failed to increase the height of a UILabel for Multi-line UITable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to resize the height of UILabel in a Table Cell. INnmy case the table is dynamic and I have customized it using two UILabel. The Table will show exactly 11 items, but two of the cells will need to accommodate multi-line text UILabel. I have selectively increase the height of two cells as follows:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 10)
         return 100;
    else
        return 46;
}
```

But I also need to increase the height of the UILabel for those two cells only. I have tried using following code (also tried some other examples from this site).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellId";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    // Configure the cell...
    UILabel *DetailLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];
    UILabel *DetailText = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:20];

    if(indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row ==10){
        [DetailText setText:[self.EmployerViewText objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

        DetailText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        DetailText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
        DetailText.numberOfLines = 0;
        DetailText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 317, 80);
        [DetailText sizeToFit];

    }else{

        [DetailText setText:[self.EmployerViewText objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
    }

    [DetailLabel setText:[self.EmployerViewLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

   return cell;
}
```

Unfortunately, the size of the UILable remained unchanged. Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have added the line 
DetailText.numberOfLines = 0; 
But it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you change the text in DetailText, you don't call [DetailText sizeToFit] again.

```
    DetailText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, 100, 30)];
    DetailText.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    DetailText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    DetailText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    DetailText.numberOfLines = 0; // Here is the key
    DetailText.text = @"test message test message test message test message test message test message";
    DetailText.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 80);
    [DetailText sizeToFit];
```

after when you change the text:

```
    DetailText.text = @"this is the modified text";
    [DetailText sizeToFit];
```

I tried this code and it resized.

Comment: Definetly the sizeToFit that is bringing you back to 1 line. UILabel sizeToFit always forces one line. Use sizeThatFits: for your multiline sizing needs

Answer (score 0):

From UILabel.h:

```
// this determines the number of lines to draw and what to do when sizeToFit is called. default value is 1 (single line). A value of 0 means no limit
// if the height of the text reaches the # of lines or the height of the view is less than the # of lines allowed, the text will be
// truncated using the line break mode.

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfLines;
```

Just allow multiline UILabel:

```
    ...
    [DetailText setText:[self.EmployerViewText objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    DetailText.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    DetailText.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f];
    DetailText.numberOfLines = 0; // Here is the key

    DetailText.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 317, 80);
    [DetailText sizeToFit];
    ...
```

You may want to set numberOfLines to 1 for other cases.

Comment: I tried with DetailText.numberOfLines = 0;
Result is same old. I am wandering if there are other issues that I am missing.

Comment: I have tried this way - [link](http://pastebin.com/pbxzkUt1) - and it worked. May be your code has an issue somewhere else...

Comment: I have re-sized the cell but do I have to re-size anything else other than the cell and the UILabel?

Comment: As I can see, standard cell made by `[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` makes it's own adjustments to it's layout. So I think, that the problem is in your cell.

Comment: No his UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; method is right

Comment: Yes, it is right, but it dequeues a custom cell that may lack default cell logic.